# Non-negativity of symmetric bivariate polynomials of arbitrary degree over unit square

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

What conditions need to be imposed on the coefficients of an $m$-degree bivariate polynomial
$f(x,y)= f(y,x)$ over the unit square $x, y \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$, so that the polynomial (essentially proportional to a probability distribution) be non-negative over the domain?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that you'll get a nice, general necessary and sufficient condition that isn't basically a restatement of the problem.

One thing you can do, given a particular candidate polynomial $f$, is look at minimizing $f$ over the unit square.  The minimum will occur either at an interior point where the gradient is $0$, a point on one of the edges where the tangential component of the gradient is $0$ and the outward normal component is non-positive, or a corner of the square.

EDIT: Some sufficient conditions might involve domination of the negative terms by some collection of positive terms.  If you assume positivity of some particular set of coefficients, you might then find suitable conditions on the other coefficients.

For example, one sufficient condition is that
$$c_{0,0} \ge \sum_i \sum_j \max(0, -c_{i,j})$$ 
where the polynomial is $\sum_i \sum_j c_{i,j} x^i y^j$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Dr. Israel. By "a particular candidate polynomial f", do you mean one with all coefficients assigned specific (determined/known) values? I'd like to have as fully general conditions as possible--with all or at least some of the coefficients as initially unknown. As you indicate, this might be too ambitious.

Comment: Thanks again, Dr. Israel. Let me further particularize the class of problems in which I am interested.
The symmetric bivariate polynomials $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ over the unit square have these properties: (1) for $0<y<x<1$, there is a factor in the $m$-degree polynomial of $(1-x)^n, n>0, m > n$, and symmetrically $(1-y)^n$  for  $0<x<y<1$;  and (2) 
$\int_0^1 y^2 (f(x,y) dy \propto (1-y^2)^n$.

Comment: The previous comment (too late to edit) should have read (note change for $(1-y^2)^n$ at end to $(1-x^2)^n$): Thanks again, Dr. Israel. Let me further particularize the class of problems in which I am interested.
The symmetric bivariate polynomials $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$ over the unit square have these properties: (1) for $0<y<x<1$, there is a factor in the $m$-degree polynomial of $(1-x)^n, n>0, m > n$, and symmetrically $(1-y)^n$  for  $0<x<y<1$;  and (2) 
$\int_0^1 y^2 (f(x,y) dy \propto (1-x^2)^n$.